Извлечь колонки из матрицы
Мне нужно из матрицы вывести все колонки. Ожидаю такой результат: [[1,3,2],[2,4,3],[3,5,4]]. Я знаю про существование Numpy, но мне надо извлечь все колонки из матрицы с помощью lambda.
Пробовала код:
arr = [[1,2,3],[3,4,5],[2,3,4]]
col = list(map(lambda x: x[0],arr))
print(col)

Результат: [1,3,2] (только первая колонка)
Изменила код на:
arr = [[1,2,3],[3,4,5],[2,3,4]]
col = list(map(lambda x: x[::],arr))
print(col)

Результат мне вернул мою матрицу без изменений.
Попыталась воспользоваться итерацией:
arr = [[1,2,3],[3,4,5],[2,3,4]]
col = list(map(lambda x: (x[i] for i in range(len(arr))),arr))
print(col)

Но всё равно я не достигла результата.
Я получила вот это:
[<generator object <lambda>.<locals>.<genexpr> at 0x000001F861CE5B10>, <generator object <lambda>.<locals>.<genexpr> at 0x000001F861CE7AC0>, <generator object <lambda>.<locals>.<genexpr> at 0x000001F861CE7C60>]

Я в тупике. Не судите строго, ведь я новичок в Python.

Вот эта конструкция (x[i] for i in range(len(arr)) - это и есть генератор, про который у вас в результате пишет. Если нужны списки вместо генераторов, то замените круглые скобки на квадратные.

Если так хотите lambda, то можно "сварганить" нечто подобное:
arr = [[1, 2, 3], [3, 4, 5], [2, 3, 4]]

# Получаем количество столбцов
num_cols = len(arr[0])

# Используем list comprehension и lambda для извлечения каждого столбца
cols = [list(map(lambda x: x[i], arr)) for i in range(num_cols)]

print(cols)

Вывод:
[[1, 3, 2], [2, 4, 3], [3, 5, 4]]


Благодарю за идею. Самое интересное, что я придумала вариант похожий на Ваш. Использовала цикл while.  arrv = [[1,2,3,4],[3,4,5,3],[2,3,4,2],[0,0,0,1],[1,1,1,9]] i = 0 k = len(arrv[0]) tot = [] while i < k:     tot.append(list(map(lambda x: x[i],arrv)))     i += 1 Но Ваш вариант запускается через 'list comprehension' ,а это полюбому более питонический и более оптимизированный вариант. Так что примного благодарна за вариант!

Чтобы извлечь все колонки из матрицы с помощью lambda, вам нужно обработать данные так, чтобы каждая колонка из всех строк была выделена в отдельный список. В Python это можно сделать с помощью функции map() в сочетании с функцией zip().
Вот как можно изменить ваш код для извлечения всех колонок:
arr = [[1, 2, 3], [3, 4, 5], [2, 3, 4]]
col = list(map(list, zip(*arr)))
print(col)


lambda пропала.

Да,lambda пропала. С помощью zip я уже вывела колонки. Мой код с zip выглядит вот так: columns = list(zip(*array) . Мой вопрос, моя проблема в том что я хочу вывести все колонки из матрицы с помощью lambda! Пошагово, присваивая вручную индексы lambda x: x[0], потом х[1], и так до конца строки матрицы - все складывается, колонки выводятся, но как это сделать не вручную, а написать код, чтобы РАЗ! И готово! Подкиньте идею! Буду Вам безмерно благодарна!
